# Excel Office Script - Send Generated Image from Excel Table

Tags: typescript, power-automate, office-scripts

Currently, I've developed a script that generates an image from a designated Excel range and then rotates the image 270 degrees. I'm attempting to export this image in base64 format to be used in HTML for a Power Automate flow. I understand that the rotated image needs to be passed as a string and believe that's currently where the issue is arising. I'm new to Office Scripts and am hopeful that I'm missing something minor.

The code successfully compiles and rotates the image, however when I try to pass the image in the following format, it is not displayed in the generated HTML file using . I've used the Power Automate section for importing other images from scripts and am confident that programming is setup correctly.

Any help/insight is greatly appreciated.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): RotatedImageExport {
  //Declare Worksheet
  const firstWorksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
  // Get the data from the table
  let print_today = firstWorksheet;
  const table = firstWorksheet.getRange("A1:O9")
  // Create image
  const tableImage = table.getImage();
  // Add the image to a worksheet.
  firstWorksheet.addImage(tableImage);
  // Get image from Excel
  let image: ExcelScript.Image;
  firstWorksheet.getShapes().forEach((shape, index) => {
    if (shape.getType() === ExcelScript.ShapeType.image) {
      image = shape.getImage();
      return;
    }
  });
  const RotatedImage = image.getShape().incrementRotation(270);
  const RotatedImageData = `data:image/png;base64,${RotatedImage}`;
  return { RotatedImageData };
}
// The interface for table
interface RotatedImageExport {
  RotatedImageData: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code just before.
In your code, `RotatedImage` is an instance of `ExcelScript.Image`.
You maybe need to convert this image to base64 before appending it to the `RotatedImageData` val.

```
const RotatedImage = image.getShape().incrementRotation(270);
const base64Data = RotatedImage.getBase64Image();
const RotatedImageData = `data:image/png;base64,${base64Data}`;
```

And then you can add it to the RotatedImageData value witch will result in a valid base64 string.

Answer (score 0):

- `addImage` returns a `ExcelScript.Shape` object, you don't need `forEach` loop
- `getImageAsBase64` converts the shape to an image and returns the image as a base64-encoded string
- `incrementRotation` doesn't return any object. `RotatedImage` in your code is undefined.

> syntax: incrementRotation(increment: number): void;

Microsoft reference document:

> [ExcelScript.Shape interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.shape?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): RotatedImageExport {
  //Declare Worksheet
  const firstWorksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
  const table = firstWorksheet.getRange("A1:O9")
  // Create image
  const tableImage = table.getImage();
  // Add the image to a worksheet.
  let imgShape = firstWorksheet.addImage(tableImage);
  imgShape.incrementRotation(270);
  let base64Image = imgShape.getImageAsBase64(ExcelScript.PictureFormat.png);
  const RotatedImageData = `data:image/png;base64,${base64Image}`;
  // console.log(RotatedImageData);
  return { RotatedImageData };
}
// The interface for table
interface RotatedImageExport {
  RotatedImageData: string
}
```